How can I create a different Google auth environment with Supabase?
I have a Svelte app and I'm using Supabase for the auth. I have setup the Google provider and it works fine but I'd like to have different environment: a prod one and a dev one.
I'd like to do that because currently I have the Google client ID and the secret for the prod version setup and when I want to log in when developing my app it redirects me to the deployed app and not the localhost.
How can I create a different environment for the dev ? I looked at self-hosting Supabase with Docker but it does not have the auth.
I'm not an expert in GCP so I might have missed something that would allow me to setup what I need.
